# Getting past independence assumptions in modeling the sum of random variables (application in education)

Tags: modeling, random-variable, sum

I'm trying to model a student's semester GPA $G$ as a random variable.

Semester GPA is a weighted (based on credit hours) sum of a student's grade points (e.g. 0=F,1=D,2=C,3=B,4=A).

We can consider the students grade points in each course $G_1,...,G_n$ as random variables, each with a particular distribution as well. It could be discrete, as it actually is, or it could be approximated by a continuous distribution (possible the beta distribution, since this is limited to an interval).

If we assume independence of $G_1,...G_n$ then getting the distribution of $G$ is not so hard. But this is not so realistic.

A few problems with this: students taking a lot of hours are likely to do worse overall than they would if they were just taking 1 of the courses, just because they have a limited amount of time. Additionally, students who do well in a particular course are likely to do well in a similar course.

How would you approach incorporating this sort of dependence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple and obviously appropriate way to model dependence in this case. One artificial way to try would be to set this up as a Markov chain where the state is the grade in the current course and you move to the grade in the next course from there. You can set up the transition probabilities for the chain to fit your belief in how likely an A is to follow an A or a B to follow an A.  If you have data on how the students did in courses over time you could estimate the transition probabilities based on the data for the students.